# Give a counterexample showing that there exist two different matrices $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\cdot A=I_n=Y\cdot A$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples

If $X$ and $Y$ two matrix of order $n\times m$ such that $X\cdot A=I_n=Y\cdot A$ for some matrix $A$ of order $m\times n$ then it must be $X=Y$? I am sure not but unfortunately I did not find any counterexample: in particular if $X\cdot A=I_n$ then the linear function $f:\Bbb K^n\rightarrow\Bbb K^m$ generated by $A$ is injective and thus $A$ has rank $n$ so that if $\phi:\Bbb K^n\rightarrow\Bbb K^m$ and $\psi:\Bbb K^n\rightarrow\Bbb K^m$ are the linear functions generated by $X$ and $Y$ then
$$
\phi(y)=\psi(y)
$$
for any $y\in f[\Bbb K^n]$ but if $f[\Bbb K^n]\neq\Bbb K^m$ then could be exist $y\in\Bbb K^m$ such that
$$
\phi(y)\neq\psi(y)
$$
but I am not able to make a counterexample. Could be that $X$ and $Y$ are equal? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Try it for $n=1$, $m=2$.

Comment: @saulspatz Oh yeah! Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let be $A:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ and we suppose that $B:=\begin{pmatrix}u&v\end{pmatrix}$ is such that $B\cdot A=I$ so that
$$
1=u+2vB=u\cdot 1+v\cdot2=B\cdot A
$$
and thus taking $u=1$ and $v=0$ for $X$ and $u=3$ and $v=-1$ for $Y$ then $X\neq Y$ and $X\cdot A=I=Y\cdot B$ as it is easy verify.